# Tiny light-colored bug ID in Amman-Jordan

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

Can you please help me identify this bug I keep finding inside my home in Amman-Jordan. Mostly on the wall and once on the bed sheet. Too small to be noticed and too light colored. I used my flash light and zoomed with my mobile camera to be able to take photo.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, for proper identification you should provide, the region / country you saw it, and ideally the season and the habitat (in the wild, in a house, etc...). Apart of this the pictures should be in a good resolution and focus, your latest pic is not perfect but the two others are probably useless as too blurred. I recommend you to edit your question.

Comment: That's the est best photo I could take with my mobile. Is it by any chance bed bug nymph?! I live in Amman-Jordan

Comment: @Rashah it is **not a bed bug of any kind**. See [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for more info for IDing a bedbug. **Your insect is a psocid (or book louse)**, which you can read more about in the [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46080/species-identification-small-insect) that yours has been marked as a duplicate of. (**See the link at the top of the page**)